# Flash-Messages in Symfony2 doesn't seem to work in my twig-template

Tags: templates, symfony, twig, flash-message

I want to add support for flash messages on our pages. I implemented 
this by following the documentation found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#index-13).

I added the following snipplet to my base layout. (i also tried to add 
it to a specific action template).

```
{% if app.session.hasFlash('notice') %} 
    <div id="flashmessage" class="flash-notice"> 
       {{ app.session.flash('notice') }} 
   </div> 
{% endif %}
```

After adding the following error is thrown

> Twig_Error_Runtime: Item "hasFlash" for "" does not exist in "MyBundle::layout.html.twig" at line 66

Is there anything else i need to do ?

Comment: what does `var_dump($this->get('session'));` output in your controller action?

Comment: Running a 2.0 symfony I use either `hasFlash()` as in your example or `{% for flashMessage in app.session.getFlashes() %} {{ {{ flashMessage }} {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 18):

do you use symfony 2.0 or 2.1 <del>(currently master branch)</del>?

for symfony 2.1 the documentation is located here: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/controller.html#flash-messages

flash messages are shown like this:

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
    <div class="flash-notice">
        {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Mmm check in your config file that you have auto-started the session:

```
session:
    default_locale: %locale%
    auto_start:     true
```

Because the error seems to be that Twig doesn't find the session class, not something about the hasFlash function. In fact I have almost exactly the same code in my layout.

Comment: I agree with that. It seems `app.session` is null inside the Twig template.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty old at time of writing so imagine you've worked it out by now, but for reference sake, it's `has` rather than `hasFlash`. So..

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.has('notice') %} 
    <div id="flashmessage" class="flash-notice"> 
       {{ app.session.flashbag.get('notice') }} 
   </div> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Doesn't work (2.6) because flashbag.get returns an array. See Manual.

Answer (score 3):

By symfony 2.6 +

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.has('notice') %}
    {{ app.session.flashbag.get('notice').0 }}<br/>
{% endif %}
```

Because flashbag is by this version array you need foreach it or use index. I m using index because i dont need something more.

Answer (score 1):

In controller

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Your message!');
```

In your Twig file

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">{{ flashMessage }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure out that flash messages are not working if `intercept_redirects` is true in debug mode.

Answer (score -1):

Did you set the flash message somewhere in your action?

```
$this->get('session')->setFlash('notice', 'Your changes were saved!');
```

Remember that flash messages will be stored on the user's session for exactly **one** additional request.

Comment: if you read the question properly, `app.session` does not exist in the twig template, its nothing to do with setting it