# Symfony2 FlashBag, Yii setFlash

Tags: php, symfony, yii, flash-message

I'm wondering why this does not have implementation in Symfony2 or Yii...

My thought is: I want to place ALL errors in flash under one INDEX = 'errors' or 'success', so that i can just render them using `foreaches`.

How flashes work now is:

(yii example) `setFlash('error','error message')` this sets flash for one message and if i do this `setFlash('error','error message2')` this will REPLACE last message. What if I have more then one error message? It's dynamical - i can't know all the indexes.

The same thing in Symfony2. I suspect this was done for a reason, but i don't know what it is. It seems to me it's far better to make indexes non-replacable, but deleteble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flash message implementation of Symfony2 supports multiple messages for the same key. If you look at the implementation you just have to use the following method of the `FlashBag` class:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function add($type, $message)
{
    $this->flashes[$type][] = $message;
}
```

Comment: Indeed you are right, my good man!:) And for "the right way" of retrieving flashes in twig i found this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240110/flash-messages-in-symfony2-doesent-seem-to-work-in-my-twig-template.