# No flashbag messages in symfony production environment

Tags: php, symfony, session, frameworks

I'm currently using Symfony 3.3.6 and experiencing some issues with flashbag messages.

The problem basically is;

The flashbag messages work in development environment, but does not in production/live environment.

```
$this->addFlash('success', 'Some kind of message');
```

The above code is being used in the controller to add the flashbag message.

```
{% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Is the code which is being used in twig to retrieve the messages. Once again this works in dev environment, but for some reason does not in production.

In [Flash-Messages in Symfony2 doesn't seem to work in my twig-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240110/flash-messages-in-symfony2-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-my-twig-template) somebody states that:
'I just figure out that flash messages are not working if `intercept_redirects` is `true` in debug mode.' This is also the case in my configuration. But what does this option actually mean? I don't want to put simply `intercept_redirects: false` in the production `config.yml` as a fix, unless this is the real fix for the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Where `$this->addFlash('success', 'Some kind of message');` is called? under what conditions is called? have you tried `cache:clear` in prod? I can't reproduce your issue for 3.3.6 + prod env

Comment: Also `intercept_redirects` is part of `web_profiler` configuration for dev env only, so it shouldn't affect you in prod env where the `WebProfilerBundle` is not loaded.

Comment: $this->addFlash is called in the controller. Cache;clear did not change anything. The Flash messages do work, but only in dev mode. I did not change the default prod config settings.

Comment: Is working php session in production?